# Displaying 3d points in gempy

Tags: python

Points not showing in 3d

I am a beginner in Gempy. I installed gempy according to the installation guidelines in an environment. I launched the "Get Started" tutorial, everything goes well except at the 'gp.plot_3d(geo_model)' level where the 3d figure appears but without the points. Whereas in '2d' it works. What is the solution?
Gempy ver. = 2.3.1, Python ver.=3.8.5

Comment: Please share whatever you have tried. Then we can try to come up with a solution for you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: show your code and example data. Maybe you have wrong data for `3D`. And in  question (not comments) you could add link to guidelines.